# I can't deploy a JavaFX Project in Eclipse due to creation of bundle fail

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, deployment, javafx

I followed [code.makery's](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part7/) tutorial on how to make a simple javaFX program.

When I eventually came to the deployment part, this is the flow in my Eclipse console:

```
Buildfile: D:\Development\EclipseProjects\Phonebook\build\build.xml
setup-staging-area:
[mkdir] Created dir: D:\Development\EclipseProjects\Phonebook\build\externalLibs
[mkdir] Created dir: D:\Development\EclipseProjects\Phonebook\build\project
 [copy] Copying 12 files to D:\Development\EclipseProjects\Phonebook\build\project
[mkdir] Created dir: D:\Development\EclipseProjects\Phonebook\build\projectRefs
do-compile:
[mkdir] Created dir: D:\Development\EclipseProjects\Phonebook\build\build\src
[mkdir] Created dir: D:\Development\EclipseProjects\Phonebook\build\build\libs
[mkdir] Created dir: D:\Development\EclipseProjects\Phonebook\build\build\classes
 [copy] Copying 12 files to D:\Development\EclipseProjects\Phonebook\build\build\src
[javac] Compiling 8 source files to D:\Development\EclipseProjects\Phonebook\build\build\classes
 [copy] Copying 4 files to D:\Development\EclipseProjects\Phonebook\build\build\classes
init-fx-tasks:
do-deploy:
[mkdir] Created dir: D:\Development\EclipseProjects\Phonebook\build\dist
[mkdir] Created dir: D:\Development\EclipseProjects\Phonebook\build\dist\libs
[mkdir] Created dir: D:\Development\EclipseProjects\Phonebook\build\build\classes\META-INF
[mkdir] Created dir: D:\Development\EclipseProjects\Phonebook\build\deploy
Using base JDK at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\jre
Exception: java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified

BUILD FAILED
D:\Development\EclipseProjects\Phonebook\build\build.xml:122: Error: Bundler "EXE Installer" (exe) failed to produce a bundle.

Total time: 1 second
```

I wonder if it has something to do with my path regarding the Inno Setup 5 and Eclipse:

Eclipse directory path: D:\Development\Eclipse

Inno Setup 5: C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5

Has anyone experienced such an issue before? I'd appreciate any help or replies, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

have you added the path to the folder where Inno 5 lies in to the System PATH variable?

For instructions on how to find it, refer to [this page](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml)

Just add the path to your Inno 5 Folder (in your case:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5

) to the end, separated by semicolon.

Comment: This is a reasonable suggestion. The installation of Inno Setup does not automatically add it to the environment variable PATH, and this error message also came up for me in a similar situation. Why aren't people responding to these suggestions? I see so many unanswered questions regarding deployment.